# bash script to search server for specific /users/ and then delete

Tags: linux, bash, rhel

I am kind of new to bash scripting and know some of the basics. I need help creating a bash script that I can run that will search a server (or multiple servers) for a list of specific `/home/users` and then if it finds a `/user` from the list it deletes that user's directory using `sudo rm -rf /user`. If it doesn't find a listed user, it does nothing. this script should be adaptable to run on multiple servers that may or may not have any users on them. Any help would be appreciated.

I posted what I have been thinking. I would start by creating a file called userList containing all the home directories I want to delete, one per-line:
/Users/user1
/Users/user30

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

do
  if [[ -d $dir ]]
  then      
    rm -R $dir
    echo “Directory $dir found and deleted.”
  else
    echo “Directory $dir not found.”
  fi
done < userList
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: This sounds dodgy: why are you deleting user home directories?

Comment: I have been asked by my boss to create a bash script to delete user home directories for employees who no longer work for the company.

Answer (score 0):

you're close:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read dir; do    # <-- there's a change here
  if [[ -d $dir ]]
  then
    sudo rm -rf $dir  # <-- and here
    echo “Directory $dir found and deleted.”
  else
    echo “Directory $dir not found.”
  fi
done < userList
```